# XML Nesting Format Using CSV Through Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a csv format file that I am trying to convert to xml using python. Right now the logic is building one block of xml per single row in csv.
I am looking for nesting of some elements in xml.
For instance my csv looks like:

```
id  addr_type  addr_line1   addr_line2   city   country
1   Home       123 Street   GR Avenue    NJ     USA
1   Office     431 Street   PO Towers    NY     USA
```

Existing XML being generated

```
<address>
<id>1</id>
<addr_type>Home</addr_type>
<addr_line1>123 Street</addr_line1>
<addr_line2>GR Avenue</addr_line2>
<city>NJ</city>
<country>USA</country>
</address>

<address>
<id>1</id>
<addr_type>Office</addr_type>
<addr_line1>431 Street</addr_line1>
<addr_line2>PO Towers</addr_line2>
<city>NY</city>
<country>USA</country>
</address>
```

Expected Output:

```
<id>1</id>
<address>
<addr>
   <addr_type>Home</addr_type>
   <addr_line1>123 Street</addr_line1>
   <addr_line2>GR Avenue</addr_line2>
   <city>NJ</city>
   <country>USA</country>
</addr>
<addr>
   <addr_type>Office</addr_type>
   <addr_line1>431 Street</addr_line1>
   <addr_line2>PO Towers</addr_line2>
   <city>NY</city>
   <country>USA</country>
</addr>
</address>
```

My current Python Code:

```
import csv

filename='addr.csv'
output_file='output.xml'

def convert_row(headers,row):
   s=f'<row>\n'
   for header,item in zip(headers,row):
       s+=f'    <{header}>' + f'{item}' + f'{/header}>\n'
       return s + '</row>'
with open(filename,'r') as f:
   r=csv.reader(f)
   headers=next(r)
   xml='<Address>\n'

for row in r:
   xml+=convert_row(headers,row) + '\n'

xml+='</Address>'
print(xml)
```

Note: Need to do this without Pandas Library.

Please help

Comment: A well Formed XML file has only one root tag.  You expected output is NOT well formed.  the existing XML is well formed.  Which is correct?

Comment: Also, does each ID always have both a home and office addresses or is one or the other missing sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can generate the required string using only `csv`/`itertools` modules:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby

csv_text = """\
id,addr_type,addr_line1,addr_line2,city,country
1,Home,123 Street,GR Avenue,NJ,USA
1,Office,431 Street,PO Towers,NY,USA"""

data = csv.reader(StringIO(csv_text))
header = next(data)
data = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row[0])

out = []
for _id, g in groupby(data, key=lambda k: k[0]):
    out.append(f"<id>{_id}</id>")
    out.append("<address>")
    for addr in g:
        out.append("<addr>")
        for h, i in zip(header, addr):
            if h == "id":
                continue
            out.append(f"\t<{h}>{i}</{h}>")
        out.append("</addr>")
    out.append("</address>")

print("\n".join(out))
```

Prints:

```html
<id>1</id>
<address>
<addr>
        <addr_type>Home</addr_type>
        <addr_line1>123 Street</addr_line1>
        <addr_line2>GR Avenue</addr_line2>
        <city>NJ</city>
        <country>USA</country>
</addr>
<addr>
        <addr_type>Office</addr_type>
        <addr_line1>431 Street</addr_line1>
        <addr_line2>PO Towers</addr_line2>
        <city>NY</city>
        <country>USA</country>
</addr>
</address>
```

Comment: Id is not related to address and the root tag is missing.